# How to get the most recent data from a table?

Tags: sql, sqlite

Here is the table that I have

```
|    Date | Value |
|---------|-------|
| 2020-01 |   598 |
| 2020-01 |   659 |
| 2020-01 |  1005 |
| 2020-03 |   478 |
| 2020-06 |   500 |
| 2020-06 |   898 |
| 2020-06 |   258 |
| 2020-06 |   654 |
| 2020-06 |   459 |
| 2020-03 |   656 |
| 2020-02 |   897 |
| 2020-02 |  1547 |
| 2020-05 |  2028 |
```

The question that I have for my query is "**Using the most recent month of data available, what is the range of estimated home values across the nation?**"

Since my table is small, I know the recent date is 2020-06.

So I wrote this code:

```
SELECT date, value
FROM home
WHERE date = '2020-06';
```

And the result that I get is:

```
|    Date | Value |
|---------|-------|
| 2020-06 |   500 |
| 2020-06 |   898 |
| 2020-06 |   258 |
| 2020-06 |   654 |
| 2020-06 |   459 |
```

Another method of code that I wrote is:

```
SELECT date, value
FROM home
Order by date DESC
LIMIT 5;
```

And I get the same result as above. But none of this two code is feasible if I have a big amount of data. So my question is, how can I get the most recent data without manually typing out the specific?

The sql fiddle is [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/838254/12)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a subquery:

```
SELECT date, value
FROM home
WHERE date = (SELECT MAX(date) FROM home);
```

Answer (score 0):

With `RANK()` window function:

```
SELECT t.date, t.value
FROM (
  SELECT date, value, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY date DESC) rnk
  FROM home
) t
WHERE t.rnk = 1
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/p2XYFL3xZPRrZm5aH5B3Cq/0).

Or with `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT t.date, t.value
FROM home t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM home WHERE date > t.date)
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/p2XYFL3xZPRrZm5aH5B3Cq/1).

Results:

```
| date    | value |
| ------- | ----- |
| 2020-06 | 500   |
| 2020-06 | 898   |
| 2020-06 | 258   |
| 2020-06 | 654   |
| 2020-06 | 459   |
```